# Imported textures from OBJ/MTL not applying to model correctly

Tags: texturing, import

I'm working on re-exporting an existing model to a game and everything imports from the OBJ/MTL files correctly except for 2 materials (textures?).

[image: Image of Horse Model]

Here is the photo of the model, all the mapping seems to be correct except for the eyes as they are completely white.

---

[image: Eyes Texture]

I took a look into the imported TGA and the eyes are in the file.

---

[image: eye texture preview]

Looking at the texture previews in blender shows the eye texture as this.

---

The same exact thing happens with the horseshoes, they are also in the same TGA file as the eyes.
I'm pretty new to Blender and cannot wrap my head around what to even search to figure out how to map these correctly.

Comment: The eyeSG texture looks like it might be intended to be used a something of a "refractive glass ball". Is it possible that the other eye texture is meant to line the eye socket, and then have a glass sphere (almost as an eyeball) refract it outwards?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I think you may be correct, when I select the vertices attached to that texture it selects the outer sphere of the eye, but when I select the vertices of the main texture it selects the whole eye (both inside and out). If this is the case is there a way to manipulate the phong2SG texture to make it work?

Comment: There probably is, but I'm afraid I'm not sure how to work with it.  I think it's largely dependent on the (intended) geometry of the object (among other things), but the way to implement it is probably unique to that mesh. You might be on to something though - What if the whole eye (both islands) are supposed to represent 2 unevenly-sized sides of the same sphere (the smaller circle is like cutting the "top" off an egg)?